# Пишу змейку в IntellijIdea на java. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему может не работать ни repaint(), ни update(g), ни updateUI()

Tags: java, разработка-игр, swing, таймер, awt

Змейка ползёт только если сворачивать и разворачивать окно ( А так стоит на месте. Может ли это быть связано с настройками самой IntelliJIdea, или проблема в моей программе? Вот код:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Snake extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    public static int length;
    public static ArrayList<Point> parts;
    public static Field field;
    public static Food food;
    public static int speedX=0;
    public static int speedY=1;
   //private Graphics g;
private static Snake snake = null;

    public static final int TIME_DELTA = 500;
public static  Snake getSnake(int w, int h)
{
    if(snake == null)
        snake = new Snake(w, h);
    return snake;
}

    private Snake(int Width, int Heigth)
    {
        super(true);
       food = new Food();
        field = Field.getField();
        Point start = new Point((int)Width/2, (int)Heigth/2); //размеры поля, а не окна
        parts = new ArrayList<>();
        parts.add(start);
        Point p1 = new Point((int)start.getX(), ((int)start.getY())-1);
        parts.add(p1);
        Point p2 = new Point((int)start.getX(), ((int)p1.getY())-1);
        parts.add(p2);
        length = 3;

       // paint(g);
    }
    public static void move()
    {
        for (Point i: parts)
        {
            i.y-=1*speedY;
            i.x-=1*speedX;
        }
    }
    public static void eat()
    {
        Point np = new Point ((int)parts.get(length).getX(),(int)parts.get(length).getY()-1 );
        parts.add(np);
        ++length;
        food.respawn();
    }

    public static boolean checkFood()
    {
        if(parts.get(parts.size()-1).getX() == food.x &&  parts.get(parts.size()-1).getY()==food.y)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public static  boolean checkHead()
    {
        for (int i=1; i<parts.size(); ++i)
        {
            if(parts.get(parts.size()-1).getLocation() == parts.get(i).getLocation())
                return false;
        }

        if(parts.get(parts.size()-1).getX() <=0 || parts.get(parts.size()-1).getX() >= field.sizeX ||
                parts.get(parts.size()-1).getY() <=0 || parts.get(parts.size()-1).getY() >= field.sizeY )
            return false;

        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        for (Point i: parts) 
            g.fillRect((int) i.getX() * 10, (int) i.getY() * 10, 8, 8);

       g.setColor(Color.RED);
       g.fillRect(food.x * 10, food.y * 10, 8, 8);
       g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (checkHead()) {
            move();
            repaint();
            if(checkFood())
                eat();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(TIME_DELTA);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

```
    import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;



public class Window  extends JPanel{
    private Graphics g;
    private Snake snake;


    public Window()
    {
        super(true);

        snake = Snake.getSnake(50, 50);
       Thread snakeThread = new Thread(snake);
        snakeThread.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        snake.paint(g);
    }
```

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Field {
    public static int sizeX, sizeY;
    public static int[][] coordinates;
    public static Field field = null;
    
    public static Field getField()
    {
        if(field == null)
            field = new Field(500, 500);
        
        return field;
    }

   private Field(int x, int y)
    {
        sizeX=x/10;
        sizeY=y/10;
        coordinates = new int[sizeX][sizeY];

        for (int i=0; i<sizeX; ++i) {
            for (int j=0; j<sizeY; ++j) {
                coordinates[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void changeField(int x, int y, boolean SetOrDel)// т - добавить, иначе убрать
    {
        if (SetOrDel)
        {
            coordinates[x][y]=1;
        }
        else
        {
            coordinates[x][y]=0;
        }
    }
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Food extends JPanel {
   public static  int x;
   public static int y;
   private static Random random;

   public Food()
   {
       super(true);
       random = new Random();
       
      x =  random.nextInt(50);
      y = random.nextInt(50);
   }

   @Override
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
       super.paint(g);
       g.setColor(Color.RED);
       g.fillRect(x * 10, y * 10, 8, 8);
       g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
   }

   public  void respawn()
   {
       x = random.nextInt(40);
       y = random.nextInt(40);
       repaint();
   }
}
```

Поменяла конструктор, ничего не изменилось(. Он же не срабатывает при сворачивании и разворачивании окна?

```
  private Snake(int Width, int Heigth)
    {
        super(true);
       food = new Food();
        field = Field.getField();
        Point start = new Point((int)Width/2, (int)Heigth/2); //размеры поля, а не окна
        parts = new ArrayList<>();
        parts.add(start);
        Point p1 = new Point((int)start.getX(), ((int)start.getY())-1);
        parts.add(p1);
        Point p2 = new Point((int)start.getX(), ((int)p1.getY())-1);
        parts.add(p2);
        length = 3;
        timer = new Timer(TIME_DELTA, null);
        timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(checkHead() )
            {
                move();
                repaint();
                if (checkFood())
                    eat();
            }
        }
    });
        timer.start();
    }
```

Comment: Возможно это поможет вам, т.к вы используете вспомогательный поток https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383481/using-a-thread-to-repaint-components

Comment: Добавила таймер в конструктор змейки, listener для него сделала, змейка по-прежнему стоит( не понимаю, в чём проблема, ща добавлю в вопрос изменённый конструктор

Comment: Вообще, java позволяет так делать, но лучше GUI элементы выполнять в основном потоке. В вашем случае в дополнительном потоке нет необходимости, достаточно таймера. Вот похожий вопрос и два типа ответа: с потоком и без https://stackoverflow.com/q/33596101/4711135

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы представили неполный пример, и не совсем понятно как вы его запускаете.

Что я сделал, чтобы ваш пример работал **без всяких таймеров**:

-Представил ваш класс Snake публичным.

-Создал Jframe на который поместил компонет - класс Snake расширенный от JPanel

-Проинициализировал класс Snake в конструкторе класса Window

-Запустил из Main просто написав `new Window();`

```
public Snake(int Width, int Heigth) {
        // Делаем конструктор публичным
        // Добавляем Jframe
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setSize(500,500);
        jf.add(this); //this - это Jpanel которым расширяется Snake
        jf.setVisible(true);
        // Дальше все по старому
        food = new Food();field = Field.getField();
        Point start = new Point((int)Width/2, (int)Heigth/2); //размеры поля, а не окна
        parts = new ArrayList<>();parts.add(start);
        Point p1 = new Point((int)start.getX(), ((int)start.getY())-1);parts.add(p1);
        Point p2 = new Point((int)start.getX(), ((int)p1.getY())-1);
        parts.add(p2);length = 3;
    }
```

Класс Window

```
public class Window  extends JPanel {
    private Graphics g; // ? Зачем это здесь
    private Snake snake; // тут был null, где происходит иниц. ?


    public Window() {
        super(true);
        snake = new Snake(20,20);
        Thread snakeThread = new Thread(snake);
        snakeThread.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        snake.paint(g);
    }
}
```

Запуск :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Window();
    }
}
```

Больше я в вашем коде ничего не менял, и он работает, без "сворачиваний". Запустил обычный дебаг, и смотрел статусы ваших экземпляров класса и переменных.

*Расширенный и грамотный ответ я предоставить вам не смогу, т.к скорее всего проблема была в архитектуре и композиции/наследовании. У вас буквально каждый класс наследуется от Jpanel...*